# Creating a list of first elements from a list of lists in tcl

Tags: tcl

Say I have a list like this: `{{1 2 3} {4 5 6} {7 8 9}}` and I'd like to create a new list made of the first element of each of the nested list: `{1 4 7}`. I Know how to do that in a couple of lines using 'foreach', but is that a more elegant way or, better yet, a built-in function that does that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Tcl 8.6 then there's `lmap` command which does mapping of a list and can be used for your task:

```
%set a {{1 2 3} {4 5 6} {7 8 9}}
{1 2 3} {4 5 6} {7 8 9}
%lmap x $a {lindex $x 0}
1 4 7
```

The `lmap` command iterates through the list `$a`, assigns the currently processing list item to a given variable (`x` in the example) and calls a command (`lindex $x 0` in te example).

Answer (score 1):

As you know that you want to search the first element , so that is optimum solution for you to use `foreach`. The Complexity will be in your case O(1). As you just need to access the first value on index which is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to using `[lmap]`/`[lindex]`, re-formulate the problem to one on a flattened, but regular list. That is, [accessing the nth (1st, 2nd, ...) element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48470087/extract-every-n-th-element-from-tcl-list) after having flattened the input list of lists:

```
set a {{1 2 3} {4 5 6} {7 8 9}}
set A [concat {*}$a]; # flattened list: {1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9}
lmap {pick drop drop} $A {set pick}
```

Depending on the layout of the input list, however, the `[lmap]`/`[lindex]` tactic is likely to outrun the above.