# Extract every n-th element from TCL list

Tags: list, tcl, stride

we can extract every n-th element of a TCL list by foreach loop. But is there a single line generic TCL cmd that will do the trick? Something like lindex with a '-stride' option.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have `lmap` (Tcl 8.5 version in the links below) you can do this:

```
lmap [lrepeat $n a] $list {set a}
```

Example:

```
set list {a b c d e f g h i j k l}
set n 2
lmap [lrepeat $n a] $list {set a}
# => b d f h j l
```

But your comment seems to indicate that you really want the *n+1* th value. In that case:

```
lmap [lreplace [lrepeat $n b] 0 0 a] $list {set a}
# => a c e g i k
```

Documentation:
[list](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/list.htm),
[lmap (for Tcl 8.5)](http://wiki.tcl.tk/40570),
[lmap](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lmap.htm),
[lrepeat](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lrepeat.htm),
[lreplace](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lreplace.htm),
[set](http://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/set.htm)

Comment: Gave this 'accepted answer' as it does not involve a proc or loop and can be given as one-liner.

Answer (score 2):

No, but you can do write a proc like:

```
proc each_nth {list n} {
    set result [list]
    set varlist [lreplace [lrepeat $n -] end end nth]
    while {[llength $list] >= $n} {
        set list [lassign $list {*}$varlist]
        lappend result $nth
    }
    return $result
}
```

and then:

```
each_nth {a b c d e f g h i j k l} 3    ;# => c f i l
each_nth {a b c d e f g h i j k l} 4    ;# => d h l
each_nth {a b c d e f g h i j k l} 5    ;# => e j
```

Comment: I like that. I would not have thought to use lassign in that way.

Comment: In my particular case n=2 so I came up with
foreach { x y } $l {lappend z $x}
But a more generic case for n is appreciated.